# Is it possible to get 2 seconds delay with timer registers in Arduino?

Tags: timer, arduino, adc

I'm doing one simple project right now. I need to write a code which changes the value of potentiometer after each seconds with the help of timers and ADC registers. I have used Timer0 for this task, everything is alright, but the output in Serial Monitor changes so fast, not in 2 seconds. Why is it so?

My code:

```
void setup()
{
  TCCR0A = 0; //reset the register
  TCCR0B = 0; //reset the register
  OCR0A = 0;  //reset  the register

  TCCR0A = (1 << COM0A1)|(0 << WGM01) | ( 0 << WGM00);
  TCCR0B = (1 << CS02)  |(1 << CS00); //1024 prescaler 

  ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN) | ( 1 << ADSC); 
  //enabling the ADC with shifting ADEN by 1
  ADMUX  = (1 << REFS0)| (1<<MUX0) | (0 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX2);
  //shifting REFS0 by 1 means setting it as AVCC
  //shifting MUX0 and MUX2 by 1 means setting A5 pin on

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  int highval = ADCH; //Data Register High
  int lowwal = ADCL; //Data Register Low
  int sensval = analogRead(A5);

  uint8_t answer; 
  answer = ((highval) * 256 + lowwal) * 5 / 1023; 

  if(TCNT0 == 0xF1) {
        Serial.println(answer);
  }
  if(TCNT0 == 0x00) {
        Serial.println(answer);
  }

}

void timdel() {

  TCNT0 = 0xF1;     // 2 seconds 
}
```

Comment: What is timdel() supposed to do? It never gets called.

Comment: TCNT0 equals to 2 seconds, but when I call it inside the if statement it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Arduinos usually runs on 16MHz cpu clock. You have prescaler set to the 1024 and 8bit Timer/Counter0. So it overflows every `1/(16000000/1024/256)` ie `16.384ms`.

But you can use 16bit T/C 1. You can get times over 4 seconds. However I'd use CTC mode and it's corresponding flag (without interrupts).